# Play-Framework: 2.3.x: play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo

I am using `play-framework 2.3.x` with `reactivemongo-extension JSON type`. following is my code for fetch the data from db as below:

```
def getStoredAccessToken(authInfo: AuthInfo[User]) = {
println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: BEFORE"); //$doc("clientId" $eq authInfo.user.email, "userId" $eq authInfo.user._id.get)
var future = accessTokenService.findRandom(Json.obj("clientId" -> authInfo.user.email, "userId" -> authInfo.user._id.get));
println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: AFTER: "+future);
future.map { option => {
  println("*************************** ")
  println("***************************: "+option.isEmpty)
  if (!option.isEmpty){
   var accessToken = option.get;println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: BEFORE VALUE");
   var value = Crypto.validateToken(accessToken.createdAt.value)
   println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: "+value);
   Some(scalaoauth2.provider.AccessToken(accessToken.accessToken, accessToken.refreshToken, authInfo.scope, 
       Some(value), new Date(accessToken.createdAt.value)))
  }else{
    Option.empty
  }
}}
```

}

When i using `BSONDao` and `BsonDocument` for fetching the data, this code successfully run, but after converting to `JSONDao` i getting the following error:

**Note: Some time this code will run but some it thrown an exception after converting to JSON**

```
play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
application -
```

Following are the logs of application full exception strack trace as below:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: BEFORE
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: AFTER:   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7f4703e3
play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
application - 
! @6m1520jff - Internal server error, for (POST) [/oauth2/token] ->
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at scala.util.Random.nextInt(Random.scala:66) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solve, but i am not sure, why this produce, I think there is problem with `reactivemongo-extension JSONDao` library. because when i use `findOne` instead of `findRandom` the code is run successfully, but the `findRandom` is run good on BSON dao. Still not found what the exact problem is that, but following is the resolved code.

```
def getStoredAccessToken(authInfo: AuthInfo[User]) = {
println(authInfo.user.email+" ---- "+authInfo.user._id.get)
var future = accessTokenService.findOne($doc("clientId" $eq authInfo.user.email, "userId" $eq authInfo.user._id.get)); //user findOne instead of findRandom in JsonDao
future.map { option => {
  if (!option.isEmpty){
   var accessToken = option.get;
   var value = Crypto.validateToken(accessToken.createdAt.value)
   Some(scalaoauth2.provider.AccessToken(accessToken.accessToken, accessToken.refreshToken, authInfo.scope, 
       Some(value), new Date(accessToken.createdAt.value)))
  }else{
    Option.empty
  }
}}
```

}